# display echo msg within same div tag

Tags: javascript, php, html, database, forms

I am making contact form which sends form data into database as well as into mail(both working fine) but when submitting form, I want to display thank you message within .mail_middle class and hide the form.

Right now I am getting message "Thank u for your comment!" instead of "Thank you for quote request" with in same class.

**I want "Thank you for quote request" to be displayed and hide form.**

Plz help me further with code as I am unaware of what to do now.....

**form.php**

```
<form method='post'>
  Name: <input type='text' name='name' id='name' />
  Email: <input type='text' name='email' id='email' />
  <input type='submit' value='Submit' class='mailbtn' />
</form>
```

**process_db.php**

```
<?php

  [...]    
  mysql_query($query);    
  echo "Thank you for your Comment!";    
  mysql_close($con);      
  include("mail.php"); 
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="middle mail_middle">

<fieldset>
    <?php include("form.php"); ?>
    <?php include("process_db.php"); ?>                                         
</fieldset>

</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

            $('.mailbtn').live('click',function(){

            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            async : false,
            url: "mail.php",
            data: { name:name, email:email, phn:phn, budget:bgt, comment:txt, loc:loc}

            })
            .done(function( msg ) {
            $('.mail_middle').html('');
            $('.mail_middle').html('Thank you for quote request.');
            return false;
            });


    });
</script>
```

**mail.php**

```
<?php

$to =  array("email-id1","email-id2");

$subject = "my_subject";
$message .= "<table border='1'>";
$message .= "<tr><td>Name    </td><td>".$_POST['name']."</td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr><td>Email   </td><td>".$_POST['email']."</td></tr>";
$message .= "</table>";

$from = "email-id";
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n"; 
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n"; 
$headers .=  'from: '.$from .'' . "\r\n" .

            'Reply-To: '.$from.'' . "\r\n" .

            'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
foreach($to as $row)
{
   mail($row,$subject,$message,$headers);
}

echo "Mail Sent.";
die;
?>
```

Comment: First. Why do you use the live function? Just a click event would be useful. Also, where is your element with the .mail_middle class?. And why do you return on the done callback?

Comment: these is what i found, as i am new to coding language. Plz do help with your suggestion...

Comment: Agreed @Cheluis, also depends on the version of jQuery being used. If it is a recentone `.live()` won't work at all.

Comment: Please post the version of jQuery you are using...

Comment: @user3423283 I understand that you are new to coding language, but to question why are you doing such things will help you to understand what are you trying to achieve. Also if you are new to the language you should try some other approaches to learn it.Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your jQuery `.done()` callback, i am not sure what the effect of having return false here will be, but from what I can see, the AJAX method is most probably not getting called.

This would be the case if your button is not receiving a false response from the `click` event.

I suggest changing your code to this...

**form.php**

```
<form method='post' class="mailform">
     Name: <input type='text' name='name' id='name' />
     Email: <input type='text' name='email' id='email' />
     <input type='submit' value='Submit' class='mailbtn' />
</form>
```

**process_db.php**

```
<?php

  [...]    
  mysql_query($query);    
  echo "Thank you for your quote request.";    
  mysql_close($con);      
  include("mail.php"); 
  $myformsubmitted = true;
}
```

**html.php**

```
<div class="middle mail_middle">

    <fieldset>
        <?php include("process_db.php"); ?> 
        <?php if(!$myformsubmitted) include("form.php"); ?>                                        
    </fieldset>

</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    // if js is supported submit by ajax...
    $('.mailform').live('submit', function(event){

        event.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            async : false,
            url: "process_db.php",
            data: { 
                name:name, 
                email:email, 
                phn:phn, 
                budget:bgt, 
                comment:txt, 
                loc:loc
            }
        })
        .done(function( msg ) {
            $('.mail_middle').html('Thank you for quote request.');
        });


    });
</script>
```

Comment: Well change your `process_db.php` echo line to be `echo "Thank you for your quote request!";`

Comment: The code I provided fixes your AJAX request, but it is pretty obvious where the 'Thank you for your Comment!' response is coming from...

Comment: I have already done that, but form is not hiding automatically when msg is displayed....

Comment: Ok after a second look, your AJAX code will never add the database entry and the send the email. Your database entry code is not included in mail.php which is what you are attempting to AJAX to. You will need to adjust your code to my updated answer..

Comment: If you are going to process the request using Ajax, don't use the form. It's hiding because the form is processing it. Don't use the form and don't use a submit. Use a button.

Comment: Also what @Cheluis said. But you can support both by attaching to the `onsubmit` of the form as I have edited above.

Comment: ok got your suggestion, but how do I make my form hide while msg is displayed?

Comment: If the AJAX executes it will. Your problem is that the AJAX was never executing. If you want to hide the form without Ajax you will need to check to see if the form submitted in php and then use a conditional to hide the form ie `<?php if (!$myformsubmitted) include 'form.php' ?>` you will also need to move the process include above the form include.